# How to convert sqlDataReader to Task async

Tags: c#, async-await, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I have the following code-can anyone please tell me if I can make this a async Task

```
public  MDTO GetIe(MDTO dtoItem)
    {

        string[] Tables = new string[] { "C", "CValue", "SP", "Ar", "P", "CR", "QC", "SR" };
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tESTp"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetItem", connection))
            {
                DataSet Result = new DataSet();
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters.Add("@ProjectId", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                command.Parameters["@ProjectId"].Value = dtoItem.ProjectId;


                connection.Open();
                Result.EnforceConstraints = false;
                Result.Load(command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, Tables);
                dtoItem.SR = Result;
            }
        }
        return dtoItem;
    }
```

Comment: Switch the signature of method, mark it `async` and use `async` methods with `awating` them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your command.ExecuteReader to the async version:

```
public async Task<MDTO> GetIeAsync(MDTO dtoItem)
{
    ...
    connection.Open();
    Result.EnforceConstraints = false;

    SqlDataReader dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    Result.Load(dataReader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, Tables);
    dtoItem.SR = Result;
    ...
}
```